# Unable autowire SessionFactory[null] into @Transactional bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, autowired

I have faced very strange issue with autowiring Hibernate SessionFactory bean into my Service.

I'm able to find SessionFactory bean in Spring Context object. So no issues with creating such bean.
But I can not autowire this bean into my service when it is marked with `@Transactional` annotation. Factory field is `null`. 
Once I remove this annotation - everything works good.

Service Class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ExampleRunner implements Runnable{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 ...
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"
                                  ignore-resource-not-found="true" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.edu" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
                  value="${jdbc.driverClassName:org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url:jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myAppDb}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username:sa}" />
        <property name="password" value="$jdbc.password:}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.edu" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    ${hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto:create-drop}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:true}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"
                          proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable runner =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml").getBean(ExampleRunner.class);
    runner.run();
}
```

Seems like when I make `@Transactional` as class level annotation Spring creates CGLib proxy bean where SessionFactory field is `null`. 
But when I use `@Transational` as method level annotation everything works good.

So I just want to understand such behavior.
What have I missed from Spring documentation?

I use Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Add your code and your spring config.

Comment: @Jens, done, please take a look

Comment: Putting it at the class or method shouldn't influence the proxy creation mechanism as your class implements an interface. How/where are you using this bean? Make sure you aren't creating instances yourself...

Comment: @M.Deinum Interface implementation doesn't matter here bc I enable CGLib proxy creation instead of JDK Dynamic. BTW, I don't create this bean manually and try to get from context.

Comment: Please add code where you use this bean. Also for fun make the field try making the field `private`.

Comment: @M.Deinum entry point code is added. `private` try has no luck :)

Comment: As long as you had fun while doing it :). Could you print the name of the class in your code (`System.out.println(runner.getClass().getName());`) just t get the generated classname.  Also try getting the bean by name (`exampleRunner`) and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum No luck with grabbing beanByName. The same null issue. Bean class name is org.edu.proxy.frameworks.ExampleRunner$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4233c082 . Very strange that it works when I use `@Transacitonal` on method level.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Couple of things about your context, try to remove the version from the xsd files, so `spring-beans.xsd` instead of `spring-beans-3.0.xsd`, for certain namespace specifying a version triggers some fallback scenario. Remove `<context:annotation-config />` as that is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`.

Comment: Basically it is strange that it is `null` as when a dependency cannot be auto wired Spring will throw an exception at startup.

Comment: Tried your code and it works on my machine... How are you checking that it is null?

Comment: Seems like xdd version generalizing helped. Now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got your error actually why you getting problem here because you not allowing container to auto-wired bean for you as you using java Main method it will not auto-wired bean that's why you getting error.

Comment: see this http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-session-factory.jsp